# BigQuery Cannot read in location: asia

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to query a federated table where the bucket is in

```
Multi-region    
asia (multiple regions in Asia)
```

. BigQuery dataset info

```
Data location:  
asia-south1
```

When I run a simple `select * from  ...`  I get:

***Cannot read in location: asia***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encounter this error because your bucket is Multi region and your BigQuery dataset is regional. The [general rule for location consideration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#data-locations) is that the external data and the dataset should be in the same location.

As of now the available [multi region BigQuery dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#multi-regional-locations) is for US and EU. Thus the error when using Asia multi region for the external table. To fix this you can either:

- Create a new bucket in asia-south1. Transfer your files from your old bucket using [Cloud Storage Transfer service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) to the new bucket. Then create the dataset in asia-south1 as well and you should be able to query without errors.
- If you want really want your data in a multi region setup, you can create a new bucket and BQ dataset which are both in US or EU. Just transfer your files to the new bucket and you would be able to execute queries.

NOTE: It is not possible to edit the location of the bucket. When you create a bucket, you permanently define its name, its geographic location, and the project it is part of. Thus the suggested fix mentioned above.

Comment: I seem, thanks. Honestly, I believe they should not allow the table to be created in the first place.